# C++20 Module multiple-layer of inheritance

Tags: c++, c++20

I found that in *Visual Studio 2019 v16.8*, the class invoking multiple-layer of inheritance cannot find its deep base class unless import the related module explicitly.

`intrfce.ixx` file:

```
export module intrfce;

export class Interface {
public:
    virtual void Fun() = 0;
};
```

`imp_a.ixx` file:

```
export module imp_a;

import intrfce;

export class ImpA : public Interface {
public:
    void Fun() override {}
};
```

`imp_b.ixx` file:

```
export module imp_b;

import imp_a;

export class ImpB : public ImpA {
public:
    void Fun() override {}
};
```

When building these files, the IDE shows there is an error in `imp_b.ixx`:

> imp_b.ixx(5,33): error C2230: could not find module 'intrfce'

If I import the `intrfce` explicitly in `imp_b.ixx`, it will succeed.

```
export module imp_b;

import intrfce;
import imp_a;

export class ImpB : public ImpA {
public:
    void Fun() override {}
};
```

But it does not make sense that a class needs to explicitly import all its deep base classes.

Is it a bug or a new standard rule of C++20?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> [7](http://eel.is/c++draft/module#import-7). When a *module-import-declaration* imports a translation unit `T`, it also imports all translation units imported by **exported** *module-import-declarations* in `T`; such translation units are said to be exported by `T`.

Emphasis on **exported** added by me.

So, I think the intention is that `imp_a.ixx` should be

```
export module imp_a;

export import intrfce; // re-export this transitive dependency

export class ImpA : public Interface {
public:
    void Fun() override {}
};
```

Imports between different units of the same module behave differently.

Comment: I have tried this, but it was not useful. I can get the same error.

Comment: I don't have access to vc++ to test, but it could be a build tooling issue rather than a language one. Does following [these steps](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2020/05/07/modules-in-vc-2019-16-5/) for multiple `ixx` file compilation help?

Comment: Reexporting `intrfce` is needed only if you want to *name* `Interface`, not just use it as an indirect base class.  (You could even inherit directly so long as you used some sort of metaprogramming to access it.)

Comment: Which suggests that it's a tooling problem and a poor error message. So what is the correct answer?